# the use of 'would' in the following sentence

Tags: grammar

Can we use **'would'** rather than **'might'** in the following sentence?

> Some students find it more difficult to sustain their motivation online than they **might** as part of a real learning group.

Comment: I would omit "they might" altogether.

Comment: Rather than asking if you can substitute _would_ for _might_ in some arbitrary sentence, you'd be better off asking a broader question requesting guidance on when these two words can be used interchangeably, and when the two words mean something different altogether.